# nodejs handling arraybuffers

Tags: node.js, buffer, arraybuffer

suppose I make a multipart, application/octet-stream request with responseType as 'arraybuffer'...suppose I receive this in nodejs and I try to write the response into a file. How can I handle this such that I don't corrupt the contents?

My current approach is something like this

```
var req = var req = restler.post(url, opts)
  .on('data', function (data){
    console.log('receiving data...');
    console.log(data);
  }).on('complete', function (data) {
    var buff = new Buffer(data) //this is prolly incorrect, but I can't figure this out at all
    fs.writeFile(file_name, buff.toString('binary'), function(err){
      console.log('done!')
    });
```

Here I write the contents into filename.
Suppose I fetch a microsoft word file...fetching it only leads me to a corrupt file. Also using restler package for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [`restler` documentation](https://github.com/danwrong/restler#options), you can set `decoding: 'buffer'` in your `opts` and it will keep the binary data intact as a `Buffer` instead of the default utf8-encoded string. From there it's just a matter of passing the buffer directly to `fs.writeFile()` without calling `buffer.toString()`.

Comment: I.LOVE.YOU. I totally missed that from the specs